# Does PDOStatement::execute clear binds?

Tags: php, pdo

Let's say I have this code:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO example (column1, column2) VALUES(:value1, :value2)');
$stmt->bindValue('value1', $_POST['value1']);

foreach ($_POST['something'] as $something) {
    $stmt->bindValue('value2', $something);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Will `$stmt->execute()` clear the previous `value1` bind? Do I have to rebind it in every loop?

**TL;DR** Does `PDOStatement::execute` clear previous binds?

Comment: If you don't rebind it, it will have the same value for every execution for the same PDO statement. You could easily test this on your own, though.

Comment: Maybe you can just execute code and tell us?

Comment: You could also just read the documentation. I'd expect it to mention this if it did http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: I did read the documentation. I'm wary of undocumented behavior.

I found this piece of code and wanted to ask here because I thought I would get an answer faster than executing it myself (including setting up a database and connection). Well... I was not wrong :)